# SAP Sybase WHILE inside of FOR LOOP

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to get this to work, but it keeps coming up with

```
Could not execute statement.

Syntax error near 'BEGIN' on line 14
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000"
Line 1, column 1
You can continue executing or stop.
```

The code is the following:

```
IF VAREXISTS('@count') = 0  THEN CREATE VARIABLE @count  int; END IF;
IF VAREXISTS('@string') = 0  THEN CREATE VARIABLE @string char(50); END IF;
IF VAREXISTS('@found') = 0  THEN CREATE VARIABLE @found char(50); END IF;
IF VAREXISTS('@result') = 0  THEN CREATE VARIABLE @result char(50); END IF;
IF VAREXISTS('@fieldsToSearch') = 0  THEN CREATE VARIABLE @fieldsToSearch long varchar; END IF;

SET @count = 0;
SET @string = '';
SET @found = '';
SET @result = '';
SET @fieldsToSearch = '';

FOR LoopGetForeignChar AS CursGetForeignChar Dynamic Scroll CURSOR FOR ( -- Line 1
    SELECT
        row_value stringToSearch
    FROM
        sa_split_list(@fieldsToSearch) 
    WHERE
        A1 <> '' 
    ORDER BY A1
    )
DO
    SET @string = stringToSearch;

    WHILE @count <= Length(@string)
    BEGIN                                                                -- Line 14
        SET @found = (SELECT SUBSTR(@String, @count, 1) WHERE SUBSTR(@String, @count, 1) NOT REGEXP '[a-zA-Z0-9]*')
        SET @result = @result + (SELECT STRING(@found,'x') WHERE LOCATE(@result, @found) = 0 )
        SET @count = @count + 1
    END

END FOR;
```

I have checked and @fieldsToSearch contains a list of alpha-numerical strings separated by commas.

Work Logic:

- Split a list of strings into rows
- Check each row to see if it contains any other character than '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
- If it does, check if it that character is already in @results, if not, add it.

This is part of a bigger SQL that works up until this point.

Comment: why is there a mysql tag here?

Comment: if this is Sybase ... there are 4x different RDBMS products under the 'Sybase' name (ASE, IQ, SQLAnywhere, Advantage); this looks like SQLAnywhere (or possibly IQ); please confirm and then update the tags to show SQLAnywhere (or IQ); if this is **not** Sybase ... still need to update the tag accordingly

Comment: @markp-fuso Sorry about that. I have fixed it now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the FOR statements are WATCOMSQL whilst the

```
WHILE something
BEGIN 
<do this>
END
```

is TRANSACTSQL.

Solution:
Use the WATCOMSQL version of the WHILE Statement which is:

```
WHILE something LOOP
<do this>
END LOOP
```